# TypeScript call async function from synchronous function and return boolean

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, synchronous

How can I call a asynchronous function from a synchronous function. I don't get it.

```
function showOpenCaseDialog(): boolean {

    let result = false;

    var regardingobjectid = (<Xrm.LookupAttribute<string>>Xrm.Page.getAttribute("regardingobjectid")).getValue();
    if (regardingobjectid != null && regardingobjectid.length > 0) {
        var regardingobject = regardingobjectid[0];
        if (regardingobject.entityType === "incident") {
            checkCaseLastOpenActivity(regardingobject).then(x => result = x);
        }
    }

    return result;
};
```

checkCaseLastOpenActivity is the asynchronous function.

The problem is, that the return result is called before the asynchronous is finished.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Although the code may appear synchronous, it is still an asynchronous function.

You may want to modify `showOpenCaseDialog` to be an `async` function, which would return `Promise<boolean>`.

```
async function showOpenCaseDialog(): Promise<boolean> {

    let result = false;

    var regardingobjectid = (<Xrm.LookupAttribute<string>>Xrm.Page.getAttribute("regardingobjectid")).getValue();
    if (regardingobjectid != null && regardingobjectid.length > 0) {
        var regardingobject = regardingobjectid[0];
        if (regardingobject.entityType === "incident") {
            result = await checkCaseLastOpenActivity(regardingobject);
        }
    }

    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the promise in ES6.

Enclose the async part in the promise and execute the return from the then part 
Please try out the following code

var promise1 =     new Promise (>Xrm.Page.getAttribute("regardingobjectid")).getValue())    });

```
promise1.then((regardingobjectid){
if (regardingobjectid != null && regardingobjectid.length > 0) {
    var regardingobject = regardingobjectid[0];
    if (regardingobject.entityType === "incident") {
        checkCaseLastOpenActivity(regardingobject).then(x => result = x);
    }
});
```

Or you can return the promise itself from the function if you need so

For more details refer
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

```
asynFunction(var1, callback: (data)=> void) : any {
.....
this._service.apiCall(var1)
 .subscribe(res=>{
 .......
 .......
 return callback(res);
  });
}
```

Usage expecting callback:

```
this.asyncFunction(value1, (res)=>{
........
........
});
```

Usage without callback:

```
this.asyncFunction(value1, null);
```